Flutter testing with Firebase real time DB - Unable to establish connection on channel
I am trying to create an app with Anroid Studio using Flutter that uses Firebase as a realtime DB. I want to create some tests to check if the data downloaded/sent to the DB are retrieved/sent correctly. I am having issues establishing a connection with the DB. I have tried to update dependencies, use the command “flutter pub upgrade firebase_core”, “flutter pub upgrade firebase_messaging”, “flutter clean”, “flutter pub outdated”, “flutter pub upgrade outdated_package”.
Every time i use the command flutter test i get the following errors (shortened to be more readable):
00:06 +0: app_test.dart: (setUpAll) Failed to initialize Firebase: PlatformException(channel-error, Unable to establish connection on channel.) package:firebase_core_platform_interface/src/pigeon/messages.pigeon.dart 210:7  FirebaseCoreHostApi.initializeCore To run this test again: dart.exe test app_test.dart -p vm --plain-name "(setUpAll)" 00:06 +0 -3: app_test.dart: 'INTEGRATION TEST - ADD MARKER ON MAP' [E] Assertion failed: '_pendingFrame == null' To run this test again: dart.exe test app_test.dart -p vm --plain-name “INTEGRATION TEST - ADD MARKER ON MAP'" 00:06 +0 -4: app_test.dart: (tearDownAll) Warning: integration_test plugin was not detected. If running with flutter drive, use flutter test $path_to_test instead. 
The code that generate this output is mainly splitted between two dart files, the other files share very similar code for other kind of tests.
The first dart file is app_test.dart:
import package:cobol_lab/firebase_options.dart;
import package:flutter/material.dart;
import package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart;
import package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart;
import package:integration_test/integration_test.dart;
import package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart;
import package:cobol_lab/main.dart as app;

void main() {
 IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

setUpAll(() async {
await Firebase.initializeApp(
  options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
);
});

testWidgets(INTEGRATION TEST - MAP OPENING, (WidgetTester tester) async {
app.main();
await tester.pumpAndSettle();

// CHECK IF MAP IS LOADED
expect(find.byType(GoogleMap), findsOneWidget);
});

testWidgets(INTEGRATION TEST - ADD MARKER ON MAP, (WidgetTester tester) async {
  app.main();
await tester.pumpAndSettle();

// SIMULATION OF CLICK OF BUTTON TO INSERT MARKER
await tester.tap(find.byIcon(Icons.add_location));
await tester.pumpAndSettle();

expect(find.text(INSERT NEW ADDRESS), findsOneWidget);
});
}

The second file is my_map_test.dart:
import package:cobol_lab/firebase_options.dart;
import package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart;
import package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart;
import package:cobol_lab/mappa.dart;

void main() {
  setUpAll(() async {
   TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp(
      options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
   );
  });

  test(Test inizializzazione MyMap, () {
   final myMap = MyMap();
   expect(myMap, isNotNull);
 });
}

In the file pubspec.yaml i have the following dependencies:
sdk: fluttercupertino_icons: ^1.0.6
google_maps_flutter: ^2.6.0
google_maps_flutter_web: ^0.5.6+2
location: ^5.0.3
fluttertoast: ^8.0.8
geocoding: ^2.0.0
firebase_core: ^2.28.0
firebase_auth: ^4.18.0
firebase_database: 10.4.11
dev_dependencies:
 flutter_test:
 sdk: flutter
 integration_test:
 sdk: flutter


For a test to be considered an integration test in Flutter, the test file must be in the integration_test directory instead of the test directory.
/test
/integration_test

You can just move the files and connect a device or emulator if you haven't.
After connecting a device or emulator, you can use the flutter test integration_test command to run the integration tests. If your project has flavors, you can use the flutter test integration_test —-flavor your--flavor command to run the tests with a specific flavor.
The Firebase Flutter SDKs use method channels to communicate with Platform (iOS, Android, etc) code, which is only possible on an emulated/physical device. Unit tests in the /test directory do not run on any device, so you get this error.

My integration_test folder was inside test folder. I moved it outside but nothing changed
This is the structure:
/test
my_map_test.dart
widget_test.dart
/integration_test
app_test.dart
usability_test.dart

@kmp222 Did you use the flutter test integration_test command? Running the command should throw an error or run the integration test.
